# vba Troubleshooting using VBProject.VBComponents to call macro

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to be able to pass a string to a function and have it call the macro where the macro name = the passed string.

I am operating with Excel 16, with Object Library and Extensibility references turned on as well as the necessary Trust Center setting enabled. Find my code below:

```
Dim b As Object
Set b=Workbooks("PERSONAL.XLSB").VBProject.VBComponents(macroNameString)
Call b
```

Code stops with error on "Call b" with "Error 438: Object Doesn't Support This Property or Method". Please advise as to how you would approach this problem. Thank you!

Comment: Try to use `Application.Run` instead of `Call`. More info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15969796/trying-to-call-a-sub-with-a-string-vba

Comment: @JustynaMK Thank you for input. `Application.Run` yields the same error.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that `Call` can only be used when run from the same workbook, in order to run it from another workbook you need to use `Application.Run`. Not sure how to combine it with your `b` parameter as it is right now - I'd personally change b's datatype to `String` and set it's value to `b="PERSONAL.XLSB!macroNameString"`

Comment: I've nixed the first two lines of code in light of Shai Rado's answer. Now I am using `Application.Run "'PERSONAL.xlsb'!" & macroNameString`, which still throws an error, albeit a different one (1004).

Comment: Thanks for an update - your updated code shows `"'PERSONAL.xlsb'!targetMacro"` while error message throws `'1004': Cannot run the macro ''Personal.xlsb'!nameISent'` why is macro's name different? Another idea is that maybe your code is in the sheet module instead of a "standard" module?

Comment: @JustynaMK thank you for continued help ... sorry both "tagetMacro" and "nameISent" are fake names used for the sake of this post. I just named them inconsistently here by accident - will change now. My actual implementation has the error and module named consistently. Also yes, these are all standard modules.

Comment: Uhh this is challenging... but maybe try to add the full file path as per this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40816455/running-personal-xlsb-macro-without-opening-excel

Comment: @JustynaMK Thanks for all your help. I restarted Excel and Shai's solution worked (shrug). I guess the whole "have you turned it off and on again" applied to Office sometimes too...

Comment: Sad but true! Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax to use is:

```
Application.Run "'PERSONAL.xlsb'!" & macroNameString
```

Where `macroNameString` is the name of the `Sub` you want to run (not the `Module` it resides in).

Comment: Thank you for input. This code returns "Run-time error '1004': Cannot run the macro ''Personal.xlsb'!nameISent'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled." For reference, both this macro/function I'm working on, as well as the one I am calling, are being run from PERSONAL.xlsb, macros are enabled, the name of sub and module are same, and running the macro manually works.

Comment: @questioner1001 can you post the rest of your code ? relevant part ?

Comment: @questioner1001 try changing the name of the Sub (not to be the same as the Module)

Comment: Thanks for continued help. I changed the name of the sub. `Application.Run "'PERSONAL.xlsb'!" & ModuleName` causes the same 1004 error where ModuleName is the name of the module. `Application.Run "'PERSONAL.xlsb'!" & macroNameString` with macroNameString as the Sub name causes the standard "View Macros" list to pop up and prompt you to select and run. The point of this function is to skip this step. This output leads me to believe that either using Sub name requires increased specificity as an input for VBA or that using the Module name is correct (but with some underlying problem)

Comment: Thanks for all your help! I restarted Excel and the code line from your original answer worked. Oops.

Comment: @questioner1001 it happens ;)